# Best way to handle Unicode in Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode

Anyone has a link or best practices for handling Unicode characters across python applications? or we need to convert the strings all over the place?

[EDIT]
Currently we are converting everything we post in urlencode to utf-8 but im wondering if there is a better way to handle that instead of calling encode('UTF-8')

Comment: In Python 2 use `unicode`. In Python 3 use `str`. If you want more help than that I suggest you write a real question with some specific details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Python documentation on unicode](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#python-2-x-s-unicode-support).

In short: internally only work with `unicode` objects. If you need to talk to outside world, `.decode()` as early as you can on input and `.encode()` as late as you can on output.

Answer (score 2):

The main thing you need to do is *understand* unicode. Realise that a `str` in Python stores bytes, while a `unicode` object stores characters; they are distinct things, and shouldn't be treated as interchangeable. All your text strings should always be `unicode` objects; everything else is binary data.

For more, check out my article on [getting Unicode right in Python](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Getting-unicode-right-in-Python).